# TestNG won't output any xml containing failed tests

Tags: xml, testing, intellij-idea, testng, test-suite

I have a testng.xml running a test of three classes, each of two two methods.

```
<suite name="idm-apitesting">
    <test name = "local">
        <classes>
            <class name = "apit.no_pojo.LoginAndConnectionTest"/>
            <class name = "apit.no_pojo.NoJsonObjectLoginTest"/>
            <class name = "apit.pojo.LoginTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

All of them fail (they must, just now). And I see absolutely no test-output.xml folder. I have put the folder name as the output directory of the Run/debug configuration page. I have removed it from there.

[image]
Still, no files with any test results appear. But I see the test results in the console as they must be without problems. If I run a class or a method, everything is the same.

Where and how can I set the place where the test results will be written?

What is interesting, if on the log tab I will set copying the console output to some file, it is declaed to appear, by default, in... windows/system32/$MODULE_DIR$ folder. But never really appears there.

Answer (score 1):

The setting to enable/disable the default reporters are available in the "Listeners" tab of the screenshot that you shared.

Please see below screenshot. You will see a checkbox which can be checked to enable default reporters

[image]

Comment: I am terribly sorry, but it was not the question what you answered, but a side remark... Let's I create a new question about this and you will answer it once again. look https://stackoverflow.com/q/47455811/715269

Comment: @Gangnus - Thanks. I have answered it in the new question.

Answer (score 0):

When I go by a text editor into the workspace.xml file and edit the description of the appropriate RunManager:

```
<component name="RunManager" selected="TestNG.C:/Users/pgangnus/IdeaProjects/idm-apitesting/src/test/testng.xml">
```

in the line:

```
<option name="USE_DEFAULT_REPORTERS" value="false" />
```

and set the value to true, hurra, it starts to work - output appears and it is in the project. (But still I do not see how to set it from the IntelliJ IDE. - created a question about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47455811/715269) )