# How can I set default reporters for TestNg from Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, testng

When I go by a text editor into the workspace.xml file and edit the description of the appropriate RunManager:

```
<component name="RunManager" selected="TestNG.C:/Users/pgangnus/IdeaProjects/idm-apitesting/src/test/testng.xml">
```

in the line:

```
<option name="USE_DEFAULT_REPORTERS" value="false" />
```

But still I do not see how to set it from the IntelliJ IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting to enable/disable the default reporters are available in the "Listeners" tab of the screenshot that you shared.

Please see below screenshot. You will see a checkbox which can be checked to enable default reporters

[image]